# How to upgrade or downgrade Internet explorer in windows phone 8.1

Tags: 8.1, internet-explorer

I want to test my code on IE version 10 on windows phone, is there a way to downgrade the IE on windows phone or to upgrade it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The version of Internet Explorer is tied to the underlying operating system on the phone, so you either need to get hold of an emulator image running Windows Phone 8 (rather than 8.1 which can only use IE11)